# selecting and displaying audio and video in html

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I am writing a program that allows users to select and display images, audio and videos I currently have the image part working. I have followed all the examples on w3schools and I think I am still having problems do to me using the java script and the select instead of stating a specific file like in the example but for this assignment I must allow the user to select from the harddrive. this is what I have so far of the important sections.

```
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML for the working image part of the application

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Image</h1>
        <a href="#page" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <input type='file' accept="image/*" onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

The non working audio part

```
<input type='file' accept="audio/*" onchange="readURL(this);" /> 

<audio controls>
    <source id="blah" src="#" type="audio/ogg">
    <source id="blah" src="#" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

non working video part

```
<input type='file' accept="video/*" onchange="readURL(this);" />


<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
    <source id="blah" src="#" type="video/ogg">
    <source id="blah" src="#" type="video/mp4">
    <source id="blah" src="#" type="video/webm">
    <source id="blah" src="#" type="video/">
    <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
        <embed width="320" height="240" id="blah" src="#.swf">
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: [w3school may not be an appropriate source](http://w3fools.com), and, I'm not sure if you actually gives different elements the same ID, but if you do, only the last element will be targeted. You can check the elements' state in developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking an important HTML rule: ID's are unique, classes are re-usable. The working image part of your HTML is the only one containing 1 ID #blah.
*Reference:*http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcssclassvsid.htm

Furthermore, if this isn't the problem: I've experimented with  `<input type="file">` as well, and it isn't a stable way of getting files YET (it will be later). Why?

1. The URL retrieved by the input varies from browser to browser. Some will only get the filename (webkit), others the parent directory, others maybe the full path.
2. The complete FileSystem API is atm only supported by the most recent versions of Google Chrome and does, as of now, not yet offer a cross-browser solution. *Reference:*http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

A last reference, should you wish to know the exact spec of the file input:
*Reference:*http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)